# Java modulus operator and PreIncrement - SCJA

Tags: java

Im revising for my SCJA exam at the minute and im confused by this question and answer. The question is what is the result of running and compiling the code.

```
    public class Test{ 
       public static void main(String args[]){
         int counter = 0;
         for(int i=0; i< 4; ++i){
            for(int k=0; k< 4; ++k){
               system.out.println("Hello - "+ ++counter);
               if((k % 4) == 0)
               break;
            }
         }
       }
    }
```

So the answer they give is "Hello-1" because 0 % 4 = 0
But my question is should k not be 1 because its been pre-incremented?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: at the first iteration, k takes the 0 value (++k is executed at the end of each iteration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop has the following structure:

```
for (initialization; condition; update)
```

The `update` is executed **after** every execution of the loop.

Therefore the following two loops are identical:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
```

Answer (score 1):

> my question is should `k` not be 1 because its been pre-incremented?

The `++k` happens at the end of the loop iteration, i.e. *after* the `if` statement.

It makes no difference whether it's `++k` or `k++`; in either case the first value of `k` is zero.

> So the answer they give is `"Hello-1"`

This is clearly incorrect, since `counter` is never incremented and stays at zero throughout the program.

Answer (score 0):

k cannot be 1. 
This is because when a for loop runs, it only updates after it has executed all the code within    the loop. Since the loop breaks even before the first iteration is completed, k remains 0.